# Error in writing script in Jenkins as a Job

Tags: shell, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a script to run in Jenkins as a job - which deletes kubernetes pvc's:

```
node('example') {
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'dockerhub-creds') {
         docker.image('example').inside() {
            sh "kubectl describe -A pvc | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$|^Mounted By:.*$" | grep -B 2 "<none>" | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$" | cut -f2 -d: | paste -d " " - - | xargs -n2 bash -c 'kubectl -n ${1} delete pvc ${0}'"
         }
    }
}
```

Now when I add this in the Jenkins item configure script area... it is giving me this error:

[image]

- error comes on line 4 which is the .. "sh "kubectl describe -A pvc ...." line
- what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I think you need to escape the `"`. Try this: `sh "kubectl describe -A pvc | grep -E \"^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$|^Mounted By:.*$\" | grep -B 2 \"<none>\" | grep -E \"^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$\" | cut -f2 -d: | paste -d \" \" - - | xargs -n2 bash -c 'kubectl -n ${1} delete pvc ${0}'"`

Comment: Or, as an alternative, I think that maybe 3 " could work in delimiting the command you want to run in sh. Something like: sh """ <your-whole-command> """

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia urs did not work. it gives "illegal string body character after dollar sign" error

Comment: @AndD that did not work sorry

Comment: Same error? And if you mix what I said with what @KrishnaChaurasia said? Escaping " in the command and putting it between """ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to surround your command using `'''` (3 x single quotation mark).
I've created example to illustrate you how it may work.

First I created two `PVCs` (`block-pvc`,`block-pvc2`) that should be removed by the script.

```
# kubectl get pvc -A
NAMESPACE   NAME         STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
default     block-pvc    Pending                                                     9m45s
test        block-pvc2   Pending                                                     9m42s
```

Then I added command to my pipeline:

```
sh '''
    ./kubectl describe -A pvc | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$|^Used By:.*$" | grep -B 2 "<none>" | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$" | cut -f2 -d: | paste -d " " - - | xargs -n2 bash -c './kubectl -n ${1} delete pvc ${0}'
'''
```

As a result in the Console Output of this build we can see that it works as expected:

```
persistentvolumeclaim "block-pvc" deleted
persistentvolumeclaim "block-pvc2" deleted
```